# I am having trouble understanding Core Data flow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, ios8

I have an App that basically starts out with a tableView That has a "+" button on the top right corner.
When the user taps this button, A tableViewController with 3 text boxes comes up. Once the 3 text boxes are filled out, the "Save" button on the top right corner of the UINavigationBar closes and adds this new Cell to the tableViewController.

---

At this point, the tableViewCell with this object has an "( ! )" for info and a Disclosure Arrow. When the user taps the "( ! )", it brings up the same ViewController to edit the content added at the start.

---

When the user taps the "Disclosure Arrow", it brings up a new tableViewController which then tapping the "+" button, displays a UIAlertViewController with a textField which a user enters a name and this new name is entered into this tableViewCell which is the Second Scene when tapping the first cell created.

---

My problem lies figuring out how to save this new name data to core data along with the Parent Cell.

Here is a Quick sketch of what i am trying to accomplish:
[image]

I Have managed to create a Core Data Managed object to save the First VC cells with an Event text.

My Core Data file has an entity Named: Events, where the property is subEventName of type String.

In the Second View Controller, a user is able to create additional Cells by tapping the "+" button as mentioned earlier which brings up a UIAlertController with a textfield. When the user enters done, it adds a cell to that SecondViewController as a Property of any cell in the firstViewController.

With that being said, I can have several cells in the First ViewController but each cell can have any number of cells saved in Core Data.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has less to do with Core Data, and more to do with relational programming.

I'm certainly not an expert in Core Data, so take this information with a grain of salt, however, I would advise you to create a one-to-many relationship from your "Event" object to your "Name" object. Essentially, each name can have only **one** event, while an event can have **many** names.

You would specify this in your xcdatamodeld file.